# Is it possible to train a H2O model with GPU and predict with a CPU?

Tags: gpu, cpu, h2o

For trainining speed, it would be nice to be able to train a H2O model with GPUs, take the model file, and then predict on a machine without GPUs.

It seems like that should be possible in theory, but with the H2O release 3.13.0.341, that doesn't seem to happen, except for XGBoost model.

When I run `gpustat -cup` I can see the GPUs kick in when I train H2O's XGBoost model.  This doesn't happen with DL, DRF, GLM, or GBM.

I wouldn't be surprised if a difference in float point size (16, 32, 64) could cause some inconsistency, not to mention the vagaries due to multiprocessor modeling, but I think I could live with that.

(This is related to my question here, but now that I understand the environment better I can see that the GPUs aren't used all the time.)

[How can I tell if H2O 3.11.0.266 is running with GPUs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269267/how-can-i-tell-if-h2o-3-11-0-266-is-running-with-gpus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new [XGBoost integration in H2O](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/xgboost.html) is the only GPU-capable algorithm in H2O (proper) at this time.  So you can train an XGBoost model on GPUs and score on CPUs, but that's not true for the other [H2O algorithms](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science.html).

There is also the [H2O Deep Water](https://www.h2o.ai/deep-water/) project, which provides integration between H2O and three third-party deep learning backends (MXNet, Caffe and TensorFlow), all of which are GPU-capable.  So you can train those models using a GPU and score on a CPU as well.  You can download the H2O Deep Water jar file (or R package, or Python module) at the Deep Water link above, and you can find out more info in the [Deep Water GitHub repo README](https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do the heavy job of training on a GPU, save weights and then, your CPU will only do the matrix multiplication for predictions.

In Keras you can train your model and save Neural Network weights:

```
model.save_weights('your_model_weights.h5')
model.load_weights('your_model_weights.h5')
```